# Power of Moore-Penrose Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Let $A^+$ be the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$. Does the following hold?

$$(A^m)^+ = (A^+)^m, \quad m \in {\mathbb Z}_+.$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. E.g. when $A=A^2=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1}$, we have
\begin{aligned}
A^+&=\frac12A^T,\\
\left(A^+\right)^2&=\frac14(A^T)^2=\frac14A^T,\\
\left(A^2\right)^+&=A^+=\frac12A^T.\\
\end{aligned}

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much for your answer! [+1]